# SwiftUI Life Cycle App: How to change Status Bar Color

Tags: swift, swiftui, statusbar

Is there a way to change the status bar color if using the new app life cycle?

I know that for UIKit life cycle there is the workaround where you create your own `HostingController` to overwrite the color.
But the new SwiftUI life cycle isn't using a `UIHostingController` at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possible workaround:

```
@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView() // or any other loading view
                .onAppear(perform: UIApplication.shared.switchHostingController)
        }
    }
}

class HostingController: UIHostingController<ContentView> {
    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }
}

extension UIApplication {
    func switchHostingController() {
        windows.first?.rootViewController = HostingController(rootView: ContentView())
    }
}
```

Two drawbacks I noticed:

- the status bar style is switched in `.onAppear` - there might be a split second when you see the previous style
- the `ContentView` will be created twice at the beginning